# Replacing Realm database file and making the new database takes effects on watchOS

Tags: ios, realm, invalidation, watchos

Sometimes, I needed to transfer the realm database from iOS to watchOS. I did that by:

watchOS part:

1. send request message
2. receive file
3. delete current realm file on disk
4. moved the new received file to the url of the previous deleted file

Above all goes fine. However, when I request the realm objects, they are still the same as the old database, though the realm file on the disk has already been the latest.

I tried to invalidate the database and get the realm again. by

```
self.realm.invalidate()
self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.sharedConfiguration)
// get all realm objects I need. those realm objects are class properties
```

and then get all realm Objects. It didn't work.

Then I tried to invalidate the database and set the realm to another realm and then set it back, by

```
self.realm.invalidate()
self.realm = try! Realm()
self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.sharedConfiguration)
```

and then get all realm Objects. It didn't work either.

What final works is set the realm to another, and get all objects, then set it back, and get all objects again, by

```
self.realm.invalidate()
self.realm = try! Realm()
// get all realm objects I need

self.realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.sharedConfiguration)
// get all realm objects I need
```

It works now. However, I will be very happy if someone would tells me there are better ways.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Now it is recommended to use CloudKit to do the bridge. Or you can try Realm sync, which is a paid service by Realm itself. For locally transportation, I still use the way within the question.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. I have same problem too when I replaced realm file that downloaded from iCloud drive. But I could not resolve with your solution. I'll look it up your advices. Thanks.